# Need help in saving Areca Palm

Tags: plant-care, indoors, palm

This is my 4th areca palm and if it doesn't survive then I guess we don't have good relationship however I would still give my level best to keep it alive like I do for so many other plants.

This plant was bought almost 3 months ago and it was doing fairly well, plant was kept in not so bright area. Recently I noticed distressed signal on this plant and moved to brighter area however no direct sun-light. Watering this plant once in a while using water sprayer.

I live in middle east(Bahrain), summer is beginning now and hence air conditioner runs in the night.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Below are photos:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plant was raised in a greenhouse. The temperature in that greenhouse was regulated for optimum plant health. Frequency and duration of watering was controlled for optimum plant health. The humidity was kept high for optimum plant health. Air circulation was controlled for optimum plant health.

Then you bought the plant and brought it into your home. Your home environment is optimized for human happiness and enjoyment, not the health of tropical plants. The change that palm has been through is tremendous. Palms react slowly to environment, much slower than many other house plants. I would guess it is showing symptoms from the move from greenhouse to your house.

What to do? More humidity  -- I think that would have the biggest impact.  You live in a desert and this palm is from the jungle. You can mist or spray the leaves every day, more than once even. You could place a pan of water under or next to the pot -- but not in contact with the soil. Just the evaporation helps. And water something like suggested in the first answer.  Lots of water is okay, but soggy soil is not.

With sufficient water this palm should stand lots of light -- but full sun behind glass is like a magnifying glass and will burn most any plant. Change in lighting (like all other changes) should be done slowly days or weeks, not hours.

Comment: Your suggestion actually did the trick, it not only survived rather it is prospering now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the pot has drainage holes, it sounds as if you might not be watering adequately, so change your watering  routine. When the surface of the soil feels just about dry to the touch, water well, with a litre or so of water, allow to drain down freely, and empty any outer tray or pot 30  minutes after watering, and again 30 minutes later if more has collected so the plant is not left sitting in water. If the pot does not have  drainage holes, repot into one that does.

Comment: Thanks a lot for saving my plant, it has been doing well since then.